# Do the aticonfig --set-powerstate and aticonfig --lsp options no longer exist?

Tags: drivers, ati, power-management, fglrx

When I try either of these options I get

```
 aticonfig: unrecognized option '--lsp'
 aticonfig: parsing the command-line failed.
```

Does the latest `fglrx` driver not make use of these power setting options any longer? In which case how is low power setting configured on the card now?

It seems `fglrx` still installs the script `/etc/acpi/fglrx-powermode.sh` and in that script there are calls such as

```
/usr/bin/aticonfig --set-powerstate=$powermode --effective=now"
```

which one can see are intended to set low power setting whenever the events laptop lid closed, or AC disconnect occur (see `/etc/acpi/events/fglrx-ac-aticonfig` and `/etc/acpi/events/fglrx-lid-aticonfig`), but these calls are going to do nothing at all without `aticonfig` having the `--set-powerstate` option.

On top of all this I noticed that `/etc/init.d/atieventd` is not starting the `atieventsd` on startup, and I traced this to the fact the `DAEMONPATH=/usr/sbin/atieventsd` was looking for the daemon is `sbin` when it actually exists in regular old `bin`.

Is this all intentional, have these methods of controlling power been superseded?